# magento - Creating a custom module and enabling payment for nominal items

Tags: magento, customization, payment-gateway, checkout, payment-processing

I have created a custom payment module and a custom gateway successfully using the following tutorials:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module

http://colourgray.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/magento-create-a-custom-payment-method/

However, my problem now is that my module would not show up when I checkout an item with recurring profiles.. how do I enable my payment module for nominal items such as these? also what are the requirements if any?

Currently only Paypal Express can be seen (if enabled), what are the conditions on why the Paypal Express payment module can be seen on checkouts with nominal items?

Comment: You should check IPN ( Instant Payment Notification ) [Working with Recurring Profiles](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles)

Comment: Yes, but in my case i'll be using a custom payment module instead of paypal. I will -not- use PayPal for this, only the custom payment module..

Comment: I wish I could help you but this mechanism out of my programming skills, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your payment method class must implement `Mage_Payment_Model_Recurring_Profile_MethodInterface` interface. Look at class `Mage_Paypal_Model_Express`. When you implement it - it becomes available in shopping cart when you checkout cart with nominal items only (as Paypal Express works now, see link from Oğuz Çelikdemir).

Comment: This is indeed a lead on to what I want to achieve, but no matter how I implement and set canManageRecurringProfiles, i still can't seem to make my payment method show as a valid payment method for Nominal Items.

Comment: accepting this answer because it is indeed the only way to start on this, however the rest of the solution is not apparent at all.